# Transparent UITabBar

Tags: ios, tabbar

I have subclassed `UITabBar` and I need it to be transparent. Like This: [image]

I have tried :`[[UITabBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:79.0f/255.0 green:53.0f/255.0 blue:98.0f/255.0 alpha:0.6f]];`

It only changed The bar's color, but The bar is still not transparent.

Please help. I have tried lots of different methods, but none of them worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
//  The color you want the tab bar to be
UIColor *barColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:79.0f/255.0 green:53.0f/255.0 blue:98.0f/255.0 alpha:0.6f];

//  Create a 1x1 image from this color
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(1, 1));
[barColor set];
UIRectFill(CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1));
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

//  Apply it to the tab bar
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:image];
```

Here's the result

[image]

Comment: Thanks, thats almost what i wanted. At least now i get the idea how this should be done.

Comment: Last question. What should i do to let tableview scroll under tab bar but let me reach last cell of it?

Comment: @KarolisRaišelis So currently it's scrolling under but the last cell is behind the bar? You'll want to look into the bottomLayoutGuide property of your view controller. There's various reasons this may not work, but if you're using Interface Builder then make sure your table/scroll view is at the very back, iOS will only adjust it automatically when it's the back most view. Also make sure the view controller's "automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets" property is set to YES

Comment: I managed to add footer for last section in tableview, so it works just like i wanted. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution based on AnupamChugh's answer

1. Create an IBOutlet for the tab bar in the UITabBarController
2. Use that to set the tab bar as transparent

   ```
   class AppTabBarController: UITabBarController {

       @IBOutlet weak var mTabBar: UITabBar!

       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()

           mTabBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
           mTabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
           mTabBar.shadowImage = UIImage()  // removes the border
   ```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor=UIColor.clearColor()
UITabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of design is the default since iOS7. Try this:

[image]

Comment: Its not that easy. I have tryed this, but its not translucent enough. Any other ideas?

Comment: I have added a photo in my question. Thats how i want it to be.